# Snort priority range

Tags: snort

What is the range of values for the 'priority' parameter in a Snort rule? The documentation it doesn't make it clear:

> The priority tag assigns a severity level to rules. A classtype rule assigns a default priority (defined by the config classification option) that may be overridden with a priority rule. Examples of each case are given below.
>
> **Format**
>
> priority:<priority integer>;
>
> **Examples**
>
> alert tcp any any -> any 80 (msg:"WEB-MISC phf attempt"; flags:A+; \
>   content:"/cgi-bin/phf"; priority:10;)
>
> alert tcp any any -> any 80 (msg:"EXPLOIT ntpdx overflow"; \
>   dsize:>128; classtype:attempted-admin; priority:10 );

Comment: Refer to `classification.config`

Comment: Thanks, that's useful. So in `classification.config` it says that priority can be manually overridden and set to 10. Is the range from 0 (lowest severity) to 10 (highest severity)?

Comment: The range is elastic. If you change the `classification.config`, you can change the range as many as you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The short answer:**

Whatever your heart desires.
Just tested up to `priority:1000000;` and works just fine.

**What it says in the manual:**

The following was put under **§3.4.6 - classtype**, the section immediately preceding **priority**:

> Attack classifications defined by Snort reside in the `classification.config` file. The file uses the following syntax:
>
> `config classification: <class name>,<class description>,<default priority>`
>
> These attack classifications are listed in Table 3.2. They are currently ordered with 4 default priorities. A priority of **1
>   (high) is the most severe** and **4 (very low) is the least severe**.

Hope this answers your question!

Comment: It's understandable.  If I wrote it, I would have put that information in the "priority" section.  Snort is an excellent IDS/IPS and has some of the best documentation out there, but it is strewn across a huge manual plus all of the different README files, and even some of the content is ambiguous at best.  A lot of learning Snort, I find, is trial and error.

Comment: It is very good overall. I've read the documentation several times now so I prefer to ask a question if I can't get the information from the appropriate section or through a quick word search.